# How to use non-'static trait objects with associated types?

Tags: rust, traits, associated-types, trait-objects

I have this type:

```
struct Wrap<T>(Vec<T>);
```

I want to implement `std::ops::Index` and return references to trait objects. This was my first attempt ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a32ae9f2e5cd7d9f9741750a688ffe78&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
use std::ops::Index;
use std::fmt::Display;


impl<T> Index<usize> for Wrap<T>
where
    T: Display
{
    type Output = Display;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index]
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and leads to this error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
7  | impl<T> Index<usize> for Wrap<T>
   |      - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
...
13 |         &self.0[index]
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         &self.0[index]
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think I know why this happens: `type Output = Display` is equivalent to `type Output = Display + 'static` as every trait object carries a lifetime bound which defaults to `'static`.

So now I can just add the `'static` bound to my parameter `T`, but this is over-constrained I think. I can easily implement such a method when not using an associated type:

```
impl<T> Wrap<T>
where
    T: Display,
{
    fn my_index(&self, index: usize) -> &Display {
        &self.0[index]
    }
}
```

No `'static` bound needed, because now the signature desugars to:

```
fn my_index<'a>(&'a self, index: usize) -> &'a Display + 'a
```

Which makes sense: the trait object has to live for at least `'a`. ([Playground with all the code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6d8852687e325e5a298b6ebc6f9c78cd&version=stable&mode=debug)).

---

**But can I make this work using associated types** (like with the `Index` trait)? I have the feeling that this might work with generic associated types, but (a) I'm not sure and (b) they are not implemented yet.

Comment: I'm not that experienced in rust, so don't count on this.
I think you have an error in `struct Wrap<T>(Vec<T>);`. Because Vec cannot save any Traits itself (they have no size, as you said) that statement will become illegal. I made a working solution with a box, but I don't think that's what you want. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6752546da134a791d1fa837f61ed1e2f&version=stable&mode=debug

Comment: @hellow Thanks! However, as you already guessed, this doesn't solve the problem for me. I really need to return a trait object and not an associated type. For those curious why I want that: I basically want to use `Index` as a trait object to do some type erasure. Like `&Index<usize, Output = Display>`. This doesn't work with `Index` directly, but using `Index` in my question made it a bit easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One attempt is to attach a lifetime to the impl:

```
// Note: won't work.

impl<'a, T> Index<usize> for Wrap<T>
where
    T: Display + 'a,
{
    type Output = Display + 'a;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index]
    }
}
```

However, the compiler will not accept it because `'a` is not used.

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/main.rs:7:6
  |
7 | impl<'a, T> Index<usize> for Wrap<T>
  |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

There are several solutions suggested by the [error code E0207](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0207), but since we cannot change the `Index` trait, the only acceptable solution is to make `Wrap` capture that unconstrained lifetime parameter:

```
use std::ops::Index;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Wrap<'a, T>(Vec<T>, PhantomData<&'a ()>);
//          ^~             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

impl<'a, T> Index<usize> for Wrap<'a, T>
where
    T: Display + 'a,
{
    type Output = Display + 'a;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let w = Wrap(vec!['a', 'b'], PhantomData);
    println!("{}", &w[0]); // prints "a"

    let s = "hi".to_string();
    let w = Wrap(vec![&s], PhantomData);
    println!("{}", &w[0]); // prints "hi"
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=497aa72a22be0fa4457d6f4011ece46e&version=stable&mode=debug))

For sure, this will change your API and that extra lifetime will infect everywhere... If this is not acceptable, you could either

- Not use the `Index` trait, introduce your own lifetime-sensitive trait instead (thus users will need to use `w.my_index(i)` instead of `&w[i]`); or
- Set `Output = Display + 'static`, and exclude all transient types. Users will need to clone or use `Rc`.

Answer (score 0):

Return a reference to `T` instead of returning a reference to a trait object and let the user cast to a trait object, or just let Rust implicitly infer from the context when to perform the cast:

```
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::ops::Index;

fn main() {
    let w1 = Wrap(vec!['I', 'b']);
    let s = "am".to_string();
    let w2 = Wrap(vec![&s]);
    let w3 = Wrap(vec![1, 2]);

    let mut trait_store: Vec<Box<Display>> = Vec::new();

    trait_store.push(Box::new(w1.index(0)));
    trait_store.push(Box::new(w2.index(0)));
    trait_store.push(Box::new(w3.index(0)));

    for el in trait_store {
        println!("{}", el);
    }
}

struct Wrap<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T> Index<usize> for Wrap<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, because I want to use the trait as trait object and do type erasure. That way one could store `Vec<&Index<usize, Output = Display>>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I met the same problem as you. "Like `&Index<usize, Output = Display>`. This doesn't work with Index directly, but using Index in my question made it a bit easier."

I didn't find out whether the Rust releases some related features or not. But I figure out a rather foolish way to fulfill my demands.

This method only works when the structs which implement the trait are enumerable. Suppose that you have three structs `Index1, Index2, Index3`, they all implement the trait `Index<usize, Output = Display>`

Then we can simply wrap these structs by

```
pub enum Indices{
    Index1(Index1),
    Index2(Index2),
    Index3(Index3),
}
```

And then implement the trait for the enum and all of its variants, there is an example for this:
[rust - How do I implement a trait for an enum and its respective variants? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066471/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-for-an-enum-and-its-respective-variants)