# How to implement a trait like `Debug` specifically for certain enum variants?

Tags: enums, rust

I'm implementing a file format parser, and I have an `enum` which reflects the general chunks allowed in the file specification. Something like:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum FileChunk {
    FileVersionChunk { major: u16, minor: u16 },
    AuthorChunk { name: String },

    // many many more variants following the specs...

    DataChunk { data: Vec<u8> },
}
```

For debugging purposes I want to implement the `Debug` trait for this enum. The standard implementation `#[derive(Debug)]` is super useful for that purpose, but has one issue: Some variants like the `DataChunk` contain huge data elements, which I want to abbreviate in the debugging output. How can this be accomplished?

---

I'm new to Rust -- naively I would see two approaches:

- Keep the default `#[derive(Debug)]` implementation but somehow override that a certain variant should have a special implementation. I couldn't figure out though, if something like that is possible in Rust.
- Remove the default `#[derive(Debug)]` implementation, and implement the trait explicitly. In this case I'm trying to find a solution that allows to only implement the specific variant `DataChunk` manually, but somehow fall back to a default implementation for all other cases<sup>1</sup>. However I can't figure out how to make such a fallback work. I tried the following as a test, but that leads to an infinite recursion, because the `write!` expression basically calls `fmt` again.

```rust
impl Debug for FileChunk {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        write!(f, "{:#?}", self)
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> the specs require ~30 variants, so manually implementing all of them would be very tedious, and there are further enums where I have the same problem.

Comment: [Here's a way to apply Mithnar's answer to your problem.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66e7287e9821481775cb96fcbfb82e3a)

Comment: `Formatter` is not really related to the whole `derive` thing. Deriving traits is implemented in Rust with [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-macros)... I'm not sure exactly where the code is for `derive(Debug)`, but that's probably not what you want because it's a lot more work than just implementing it manually, given you only have one struct to worry about.

Comment: Other related questions might be: [Can traits be used on enum types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567350/3650362), [How do I implement a trait for an enum and its respective variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57066471/3650362), and [Is there a way to use existing structs as enum variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49705007/3650362)

Comment: [Apparently `derive(Debug)` is still built in to the compiler, despite proc macros being stable now.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/fmt/mod.rs#L556)

Comment: How does the new type pattern relate to this example? Feel free to convert your comment into an answer. I failed to see the immediate connection to the other question, so a concrete answer would still help newcomers.

Comment: I did create a newtype, but you might have overlooked it because it has the same name as the variant (`DataChunk`).

Comment: Now I get it. I basically need another layer of nesting. Not so nice that I have an unnecessary nesting just for getting my debug output right though :-/.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "necessary", I guess :-) The way I see it, one of your variants is "`Vec<u8>`, but with a different `Debug` behavior", which is semantically a different type than just "`Vec<u8>`". But I can see how it might be useful to have a more flexible `Debug` macro. [(There are other reasons why `derive`ing doesn't always give the right answer that I'd like to see addressed.)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925)